# Spark Streaming Application not running jobs concurrently

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark Streaming Job thats reading from Kafka and saving it into Redshift.

The batch of RDD contains data with a column "groupId", however the follow code below isn't running forEach concurrently, its running it serially in Yarn Client Mode.

Yarn Environment:

- Client Mode
- Default Scheduler FIFO
- Exector Instances 3+
- Executor: 2 Cores, 2 GB

```
  inputDstream.foreachRDD { eventRdd: RDD[Event] =>
      ...
      // Convert eventRdd to eventDF
      val groupIds = eventDF.select("group_id").distinct.collect.flatMap(_.toSeq)
      groupIds.par.foreach{ groupId =>
          val teventDF = eventDF.where($"group_id" <=> groupId)
          val teventDFWithVersion = teventDF.withColumn("schema_id", lit(version))
          teventDFWithVersion.write
            .format("io.github.spark_redshift_community.spark.redshift")
            .options(opts)
            .mode("Append")
            .save()
       }
  }
```

Again, the operation in groupsIds.par.foreach is running serially, instead of parallel. With increase in groups, my application starts to choke up and processing time spikes.

How do I get Spark to save my batches of data concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

Driver is running on m5.large (2 CPU) but only has 1 CPU for the Driver Application since other services are occupying the other CPU.

array.par.foreach{} runs concurrently based on the number of vCPUS available.

Running the Driver with more CPU allows more concurrent writes.

Solution: Run the Spark Driver Application in Client mode on machine with more CPU. Or run Spark Application as Cluster Mode with --driver-cores 4.